# Text as a node: three.js / ngraph.tree

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js

I'm trying to create some sort of 3D network (network of people) for in a browser using three.js and ngraph.
The graph is created and everything looks fine but the nodes in the graph display as squares. I would like to replace the squares with the text "node" (which will later be replaced with the name of the people in the network), however, I have no idea to display the text instead of the squares that are shown now.. Please help!

I found this code in .../ngraph.three/lib/default.js, which is where the squares are created:

```js
function createNodeUI(node) {

  var nodeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xfefefe });

  var nodeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(NODE_SIZE, NODE_SIZE, NODE_SIZE);

  return new THREE.Mesh(nodeGeometry, nodeMaterial);
  
  }
```

And this in .../ngraph.three/node_modules/three/three.js:

```js
case 'BoxGeometry':

  case 'CubeGeometry': // backwards compatible

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(

     data.width,

        data.height,

     data.depth,

     data.widthSegments,

     data.heightSegments,

        data.depthSegments

    );
```

I suppose I need something around those lines for the text as well, but I know too little of js to figure it out..

In the meantime I have tried several tutorials and manuals, but when I try to remove the squares and replace them with text, the whole graph disappears.

For example with this code:

```js
function createNodeUI(node) {

  var nodeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xfefefe});

  var nodeGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry("text", {font:'helvetiker'});

  return new THREE.Mesh(nodeGeometry, nodeMaterial);  
 
}
```

using:

```js
THREE.TextGeometry = function ( text, parameters ) {



 parameters = parameters || {};



 var textShapes = THREE.FontUtils.generateShapes( text, parameters );



 // translate parameters to ExtrudeGeometry API



 parameters.amount = parameters.height !== undefined ? parameters.height : 50;



 // defaults



 if ( parameters.bevelThickness === undefined ) parameters.bevelThickness = 10;

 if ( parameters.bevelSize === undefined ) parameters.bevelSize = 8;

 if ( parameters.bevelEnabled === undefined ) parameters.bevelEnabled = false;



 THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.call( this, textShapes, parameters );



 this.type = 'TextGeometry';



};



THREE.TextGeometry.prototype = Object.create( THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.prototype );

THREE.TextGeometry.prototype.constructor = THREE.TextGeometry;
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TextGeometry

Comment: yup, I have looked at that, however, when I try to use textgeometry, the whole graph seems to disappear for no reason, so I hoped there would be different options as well..

Comment: then you have to ask specific questions on those problems

Comment: I'll add it, after you posted that I took a look and figured that out, didn't know yet when I asked the question :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently it was quite simple..

What went wrong is that the font 'helvetiker' could not be found. This caused the whole graph to disappear as it tried to create the nodes (text) before the lines in the graph, which it could not and thus did not continue to draw the lines.
Even though I did not figure out how to get it to find the 'helvetiker' font, I did solve the problem by hard-coding the font into my three.js (I know, I know, not good..)

So if people encountered the same problem as me, here is my 'solution':

```
function createNodeUI(node) {
   var nodeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [
     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x00cccc, shading:   THREE.FlatShading } ), // front
     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) // side

   ] );

   var nodeGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( node.data, { size: 5, height: 2, curveSegments: 6, font: "helvetiker", weight: "normal", style: "normal" });

   return new THREE.Mesh(nodeGeometry, nodeMaterial);
```

}

and the hard-coded part:

```
loadFace: function ( data ) {
    data = {"glyphs":{"ο":{"x_min":0,"x_max":712,"ha":815,"o":"m 356 -25 q 96 88 192 -25 q 0 368 0 201 q 92 642 0 533 q 356 761 192 761 q 617 644 517 761 q 712 368 712 533 q 619 91 712 201 q 356 -25 520 -25 m 356 85 q 527 175 465 85 q 583 369 583 255 q 528 562 583 484 q 356 651 466 651 q 189 560 250 651 q 135 369 135 481 q 187 177 135 257 q 356 85 250 85 "},"S":{"x_min":0,"x_max":788,"ha":890,"o":"m 788 291 q 662 54 788 144 q 397 -26 550 -26 q 116 68 226 -26 q 0 337 0 168 l 131 337 q 200 152 131 220 q 384 85 269 85 q 557 129 479 85 q 650 270 650 183 q 490 429 650 379 q 194 513 341 470 q 33 739 33 584 q 142 964 33 881 q 388 1041 242 1041 q 644 957 543 1041 q 756 716 756 867 l 625 716 q 561 874 625 816 q 395 933 497 933 q 243 891 309 933 q 164 759 164 841 q 325 609 164 656 q 625 526 475 568 q 788 291 788 454 "},"¦":{"x_min":343,"x_max":449,"ha":792,"o":"m 449 462 l 343 462 l 343 986 l 449 986 l 449 462 m 449 -242 l 343 -242 l 343 280 l 449 280 l 449 -242 "},"/":{"x_min":183.25,"x_max":608.328125,"ha":792,"o":"m 608 1041 l 266 -129 l 183 -129 l 520 1041 l 608 1041 "},"Τ":{"x_min":-0.4375,"x_max":777.453125,"ha":839,"o":"m 777 893 l 458 893 l 458 0 l 319 0 l 319 892 l 0 892 l 0 1013 l 777 1013 l 777 893 "},"y":{"x_min":0,"x_max":684.78125,"ha":771,"o":"m 684 738 l 388 -83 q 311 -216 356 -167 q 173 -279 252 -279 q 97 -266 133 -279 l 97 -149 q 132 -155 109 -151 q 168 -160 155 -160 q 240 -114 213 -160 q 274 -26 248 -98 l 0 738 l 137 737 l 341 139 l 548 737 l 684 738 "},"Π":{"x_min":0,"x_max":803,"ha":917,"o":"m 803 0 l 667 0 l 667 886 l 140 886 l 140 0 l 0 0 l 0 1012 l 803 1012 l 803 0 "},"ΐ":{"x_min":-111,"x_max":339,"ha":361,"o":"m 339 800 l 229 800 l 229 925 l 339 925 l 339 800 m -1 800 l -111 800 l -111 925 l -1 925 l -1 800 m 284 3 q 233 -10 258 -5 q 182 -15 207 -15 q 85 26 119 -15 q 42 200 42 79 l 42 737 l 167 737 l 168 215 q 172 141 168 157 q 226 101 183 101 q 248 103 239 101 q 284 112 257 104 l 284 3 m 302 1040 l 113 819 l 30 819 l 165 1040 l 302 1040 "},"g":{"x_min":0,"x_max":686,"ha":838,"o":"m 686 34 q 586 -213 686 -121 q 331 -306 487 -306 q 131 -252 216 -306 q 31 -84 31 -190 l 155 -84 q 228 -174 166 -138 q 345 -207 284 -207 q 514 -109 454 -207 q 564 89 564 -27 q 461 6 521 36 q 335 -23 401 -23 q 88 100 184 -23 q 0 370 0 215 q 87 634 0 522 q 330 758 183 758 q 457 728 398 758 q 564 644 515 699 l 564 737 l 686 737 l 686 34 m 582 367 q 529 560 582 481 q 358 652 468 652 q 189 561 250 652 q 135 369 135 482 q 189 176 135 255 q 361 85 251 85 q 529 176 468 85 q 582 367 582 255 "},"²":{"x_min":0,"x_max":442,"ha":539,"o":"m 442 383 l 0 383 q 91 566 0 492 q 260 668 176 617 q 354 798 354 727 q 315 875 354 845 q 227 905 277 905 q 136 869 173 905 q 99 761 99 833 l 14 761 q 82 922 14 864 q 232 974 141 974 q 379 926 316 974 q 442 797 442 878 q 351 635 442 704 q 183 539 321 611 q 92 455 92 491 l 442 455 l 442 383 "},"–":{"x_min":0,"x_max":705.5625,"ha":803,"o":"m 705 334 l 0 334 l 0 410 l 705 410 l 705 334 "},"Κ":{"x_min":0,"x_max":819.5625,"ha":893,"o":"m 819 0 l 650 0 l 294 509 l 139 356 l 139 0 l 0 0 l 0 1013 l 139 1013 l 139 526 l 626 1013 l 809 1013 l 395 600 l 819 0 "},"ƒ":{"x_min":-46.265625,"x_max":392,"ha":513,"o":"m 392 651 l 259 651 l 79 -279 l -46 -278 l 134 651 l 14 651 l 14 751 l 135 751 q 151 948 135 900 q 304 1041 185 1041 q 334 1040 319 1041 q 392 1034 348 1039 l 392 922 q 337 931 360 931 q 271 883 287 931 q 260 793 260 853 l 260 751 l 392 751 l 392 651 "},"e":{"x_min":0,"x_max":714,"ha":813,"o":"m 714 326 l 140 326 q 200 157 140 227 q 359 87 260 87 q 488 130 431 87 q 561 245 545 174 l 697 245 q 577 48 670 123 q 358 -26 484 -26 q 97 85 195 -26 q 0 363 0 197 q 94 642 0 529 q 358 765 195 765 q 626 627 529 765 q 714 326 714 503 m 576 429 q 507 583 564 522 q 355 650 445 650 q 206 583 266 650 q 140 429 152 522 l 576 429 "},"ό":{"x_min":0,"x_max":712,"ha":815,"o":"m 356 -25 q 94 91 194 -25 q 0 368 0 202 q 92 642 0 533 q 356 761 192 761 q 617 644 517 761 q 712 368 712 533 q 619 91 712 201 q 356 -25 520 -25 m 356 85 q 527 175 465 85 q 583 369 583 255 q 528 562 583 484 q 356 651 466 651 q 189 560 250 651 q 135 369 135 481 q 187 177 135 257 q 356 85 250 85 m 576 1040 l 387 819 l 303 819 l 438 1040 l 576 1040 "},"J":{"x_min":0,"x_max":588,"ha":699,"o":"m 588 279 q 287 -26 588 -26 q 58 73 126 -26 q 0 327 0 158 l 133 327 q 160 172 133 227 q 288 96 198 96 q 426 171 391 96 q 449 336 449 219 l 449 1013 l 588 1013 l 588 279 "},"»":{"x_min":-1,"x_max":503,"ha":601,"o":"m 503 302 l 280 136 l 281 256 l 429 373 l 281 486 l 280 608 l 503 440 l 503 302 m 221 302 l 0 136 l 0 255 l 145 372 l 0 486 l -1 608 l 221 440 l 221 302 "},"©":{"x_min":-3,"x_max":1008,"ha":1106,"o":"m 502 -7 q 123 151 263 -7 q -3 501 -3 294 q 123 851 -3 706 q 502 1011 263 1011 q 881 851 739 1011 q 1008 501 1008 708 q 883 151 1008 292 q 502 -7 744 -7 m 502 60 q 830 197 709 60 q 940 501 940 322 q 831 805 940 681 q 502 944 709 944 q 174 805 296 944 q 65 501 65 680 q 173 197 65 320 q 502 60 294 60 m 741 394 q 661 246 731 302 q 496 190 591 190 q 294 285 369 190 q 228 497 228 370 q 295 714 228 625 q 499 813 370 813 q 656 762 588 813 q 733 625 724 711 l 634 625 q 589 704 629 673 q 498 735 550 735 q 377 666 421 735 q 334 504 334 597 q 374 340 334 408 q 490 272 415 272 q 589 304 549 272 q 638 394 628 337 l 741 394 "},"ώ":{"x_min":0,"x_max":922,"ha":1030,"o":"m 687 1040 l 498 819 l 415 819 l 549 1040 l 687 1040 m 922 339 q 856 97 922 203 q 650 -26 780 -26 q 538 9 587 -26 q 461 103 489 44 q 387 12 436 46 q 277 -22 339 -22 q 69 97 147 -22 q 0 338 0 202 q 45 551 0 444 q 161 737 84 643 l 302 737 q 175 552 219 647 q 124 336 124 446 q 155 179 124 248 q 275 88 197 88 q 375 163 341 88 q 400 294 400 219 l 400 572 l 524 572 l 524 294 q 561 135 524 192 q 643 88 591 88 q 762 182 719 88 q 797 341 797 257 q 745 555 797 450 q 619 737 705 637 l 760 737 q 874 551 835 640 q 922 339 922 444 "},"^":{"x_min":193.0625,"x_max":598.609375,"ha":792,"o":"m 598 772 l 515 772 l 395 931 l 277 772 l 193 772 l 326 1013 l 462 1013 l 598 772 "},"«":{"x_min":0,"x_max":507.203125,"ha":604,"o":"m 506 136 l 284 302 l 284 440 l 506 608 l 507 485 l 360 371 l 506 255 l 506 136 m 222 136 l 0 302 l 0 440 l 222 608 l 221 486 l 73 373 l 222 256 l 222 136 "},"D":{"x_min":0,"x_max":828,"ha":935,"o":"m 389 1013 q 714 867 593 1013 q 828 521 828 729 q 712 161 828 309 q 382 0 587 0 l 0 0 l 0 1013 l 389 1013 m 376 124 q 607 247 523 124 q 681 510 681 355 q 607 771 681 662 q 376 896 522 896 l 139 896 l 139 124 l 376 124 "},"∙":{"x_min":0,"x_max":142,"ha":239,"o":"m 142 585 l 0 585 l 0 738 l 142 738 l 142 585 "},"ÿ":{"x_min":0,"x_max":47,"ha":125,"o":"m 47 3 q 37 -7 47 -7 q 28 0 30 -7 q 39 -4 32 -4 q 45 3 45 -1 l 37 0 q 28 9 28 0 q 39 19 28 19 l 47 16 l 47 19 l 47 3 m 37 1 q 44 8 44 1 q 37 16 44 16 q 30 8 30 16 q 37 1 30 1 m 26 1 l 23 22 l 14 0 l 3 22 l 3 3 l 0 25 l 13 1 l 22 25 l 26 1 "},"w":{"x_min":0,"x_max":1009.71875,"ha":1100,"o":"m 1009 738 l 783 0 l 658 0 l 501 567 l 345 0 l 222 0 l 0 738 l 130 738 l 284 174 l 432 737 l 576 738 l 721 173 l 881 737 l 1009 738 "},"$":{"x_min":0,"x_max":700,"ha":793,"o":"m 664 717 l 542 717 q 490 825 531 785 q 381 872 450 865 l 381 551 q 620 446 540 522 q 700 241 700 370 q 618 45 700 116 q 381 -25 536 -25 l 381 -152 l 307 -152 l 307 -25 q 81 62 162 -25 q 0 297 0 149 l 124 297 q 169 146 124 204 q 307 81 215 89 l 307 441 q 80 536 148 469 q 13 725 13 603 q 96 910 13 839 q 307 982 180 982 l 307 1077 l 381 1077 l 381 982 q 574 917 494 (.......................... etc..)
```

If someone knows a better way to do this, please let me know, but so far this works fine :)